# I want to delete duplication with condition from a table in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to delete the dup lines using PLSQL. The sample of the table is below

| Policy # | Price | Dealno for Loan # | Price of Loan | PersonID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | Loan123 | 1,000 | abc |
| 123 | 10 | Loan123 | 3,000 | abc |
| 456 | 10 | Loan456 | 500 | xyz |
| 456 | 10 | Loan456 | 500 | null |

As you can see, in the case of Policy #123, I try to get the line with the highest amount of Price of Loan. Which mean the Price of Loan for 3,000.
For Policy #456, I want to get the one without null value.

Is there a way for me to achieve that in PLSQL.

Thank you

Comment: Do you actually mean `DELETE`? Or are you just trying to `SELECT` certain rows?  Also, this seems like you are looking for a simple DML statement.  Do you really need PL/SQL?

Comment: Yes, I actually mean delete because later on, I may use it for calculating the total price. If there is a dup, it may get the incorrect result.
For the question, do I need PL/SQL, yes I do. I am trying to pull out the table from PL/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query identifies if a row is *OK* (`rn = 1`) or if is is a duplicated copy (`rn > 1`) based on your definition

```
select POLICY#, PRICE, LOAN#, PRICE_LOAN, PERSON_ID,
row_number() over (partition by POLICY# order by PRICE_LOAN desc, PERSON_ID nulls last) as rn
from tab
;


   POLICY#      PRICE LOAN#    PRICE_LOAN PER         RN
---------- ---------- -------- ---------- --- ----------
       123         10 loan123        3000 abc          1
       123         10 loan123        1000 abc          2
       456         10 loan4563        500 xyz          1
       456         10 loan4563        500              2
```

Note that you use `row_number` where you `partition by` on the *unique key*  and `order by` so that you get first the row that should be taken.

So to get the duplicates only you use this query

```
with rn as (
select POLICY#, PRICE, LOAN#, PRICE_LOAN, PERSON_ID,
row_number() over (partition by POLICY# order by PRICE_LOAN desc, PERSON_ID nulls last) as rn
from tab
)
select * from rn where rn > 1;

   POLICY#      PRICE LOAN#    PRICE_LOAN PER         RN
---------- ---------- -------- ---------- --- ----------
       123         10 loan123        1000 abc          2
       456         10 loan4563        500              2
```

Based on this you write the `DELETE` statement (enclose in `BEGIN` ... `END` if you insist in PL/SQL)

```
delete from tab where rowid in
(
with rn as (
select POLICY#, PRICE, LOAN#, PRICE_LOAN, PERSON_ID,
row_number() over (partition by POLICY# order by PRICE_LOAN desc, PERSON_ID nulls last) as rn
from tab
)
select rowid from rn where rn > 1
);
```

You may check if the delete worked fine ....

```
select * from tab;

   POLICY#      PRICE LOAN#    PRICE_LOAN PER
---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---
       123         10 loan123        3000 abc
       456         10 loan4563        500 xyz
```

... and `commit`